# Simplifying Logical formulas

Tags: logic

Simplify the logical operators below

a.  ¬[ ¬Q ∨ (¬P ∧ Q) ]

b.  ((P ∧ Q) ∧ ¬R) ∨ [P ∧ ¬(Q ∨ R)]

Am not able to start this of. I know what all the symbols mean but not able to simplify

Comment: Write out the truth tables of the given formulas, and think about simpler formulas that can produce the same tables.

Comment: Have you heard of [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) before? Also, once you're through with De Morgan's Laws with the second one, use the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) to factor out $P \wedge R$.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added at least *some* work--any at all. Any. Literally. At all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you heard of [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) before? Apply this to both expressions.

Once you're through with De Morgan's Laws with the first one, you have:
$$Q \wedge (P \vee \sim Q)$$
Now, use [distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) to distribute the $Q$ over the disjunction and eliminate $Q \wedge \sim Q$.

Also, once you're through with De Morgan's Laws with the second one, you have:
$$(P \wedge Q \wedge \sim R) \vee (P \wedge \sim Q \wedge \sim R)$$
Now, use the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) to factor out $P \wedge \sim R$ and eliminate $Q \wedge \sim Q$.

Answer (score 2):

(a) $$¬[ ¬Q ∨ (¬P ∧ Q) ] = ¬[ (¬Q ∨ ¬P) ∧ (¬Q ∨ Q) ] = ¬[ (¬Q ∨ ¬P) ] = Q ∧ P$$

(b)  $$((P ∧ Q) ∧ ¬R) ∨ [P ∧ ¬(Q ∨ R)] = (P ∧ Q ∧ ¬R) ∨ [P ∧ ¬(Q ∨ R)] =  [((P ∧ Q ∧ ¬R) ∨ P) ∧ ((P ∧ Q ∧ ¬R) ∨ ¬(Q ∨ R))] =  [P ∧ ((P ∧ Q ∧ ¬R) ∨ (¬Q ∧ ¬R))] = [P ∧ ¬R∧((P ∧ Q  ) ∨ (¬Q))] = [P ∧ ¬R∧(P∨ ¬Q)  ]=  P ∧ ¬R  $$